# [Google App Engine]How to use filter()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filter

I'm getting started with Google App Engine, and I want to make something like twitter.

```
class User(db.Model):
  account = db.StringProperty()
  password = db.StringProperty()
  name = db.StringProperty()

class Message(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty()
  text = StringProperty()
  created = DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

How to get particular person's tweet?
I try

```
que = db.Query(Message).order('-created').filter("user['account'] = ",'Tom')
```

But this is error.
Can I access the user properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no GQL `JOIN` operation.  Check out the article on [modeling relationships](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) for some other techniques you can use.  Also, be sure to watch [Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html), it will be well worth your time.

With your current models, you would need to fetch the user entity (or build its key!) then query using that.  For example:

```
user = User.all(keys_only=True).filter('account', 'Tom').get()  # only get one.
# or, build the key (if possible)
user = db.Key.from_path('User', 'tom')  # if you make 'account' the key_name

messages = Message.all().order('-created').filter("user =", user)
```

Another choice is to denomalize the desgin and store 'account' on the message as well:

```
class Message(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty()
  account = StringProperty()
  text = StringProperty()
  created = DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

messages = Message.all().order('-created').filter("account =", 'tom')
```

Answer (score 0):

What Robert Kluin said was right. Also i see this in your model.

```
user = db.ReferenceProperty()
```

I think it is supposed to be `user=db.ReferenceProperty(User)`

Comment: Just a note, you do not have to specify a 'target' kind in a ReferenceProperty.